# Vectorizing a loop in R

Tags: r, loops

There must be a simple way to vectorize the following loop in R, but I can't see it.

```
w <- numeric(10)
z <- rnorm(20)
v <- c(sample(1:10,10),sample(1:10,10)) #Random ordering of c(1:10,1:10)
for(i in 1:10)
    w[i] <- sum(z[v==i])
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

another approach

```
w = rowsum(z, v)
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even know that function existed. Super fast too.

Comment: I was not familiar with it either, till I had to explore ways to speed up my code. That was when I came across a treasure trove of functions: (1) rowsum, (2) max.col etc. which speed up specific operations that are generally implemented using apply family.

Answer (score 3):

You could use aggregate:
    aggregate(z, by=list(v), sum)

Comment: I tend to think of aggregate of being equivalent to looping.  It doesn't have the same performance improvement of vectorization.

Comment: aggregate was a lot faster than the loop I had, but nowhere near as fast as rowsum()

Comment: @Rob as Shane  mentioned, aggregate simply calls lapply; while rowsum is probably a direct call to a C function.