# Creating a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am a newbie for R and still trying to learn how to create a for loop. Can anyone share how to create a for loop for `h(x,n) = 1+x+x^2 +···+x^n`. Many thanks!

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vectorizing a loop in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172379/vectorizing-a-loop-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop. You need a function that uses vectorization -

```
h <- function(x, n) {
  sum(1, x^seq_len(n))
}

h(2, 2)
[1] 7
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `for` loop, but pedagogically:

```
x <- 2 ; n <- 2
ret <- 1
for (i in seq_len(n)) ret <- ret + x^i
ret
# [1] 15
```

That looks horrible to me: it might be clear (which is good), but there are certainly better ways in R to do it. (In other languages, that is precisely how you might need to do it. That's fine, they may not be efficient in vectorized math the way R is.)

Okay, let's do a little refinement of it, using `seq_len(n)` as a starting point. The `sapply` function will do the provided function for every value within the `seq`uence, so

```
1 + sum(sapply(seq_len(n), function(i) x^i))
# [1] 15
```

That's all well-and-good, but it's calling this anon-function once for each value within `seq_len(n)`. Let's just do it *once*, without iterating over each value within the sequence:

```
1 + sum(x^seq_len(n))
# [1] 15
```

Explanation: when you do `x^seq_len(3)`, this is effectively `x^c(1,2,3)`, which is effectively (though semantically different from) `c(x^1, x^2, x^3)`, almost an algebraic expansion of things. Wrapping it in `sum` is simple enough.

Okay, as Shree suggested, it can easily be a function to help you out in case you need to do this multiple times. I'll reduce that example a little, as `rep(x,n)` is not necessary:

```
h <- function(x, n) sum(1, x^seq_len(n))
h(x, n)
# [1] 15
```

Comment: Just FYI, I removed `rep()` from my answer. Thanks!